# on 18.04 "sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev" failing, .deb files timeout via synaptic and browser as well

Tags: apt, 18.04, boost

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

results in:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libboost1.65-dev 
amd64 1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5                                                
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch 
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.65.1/libboost1.65- 
dev_1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

**Can't access 4 .deb files directly via browser either:**
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.65.1/

[Browser Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTkpM.png)

Text list of files that can't be downloaded from browser in case image fails:

libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dsfg-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb

libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dsfg-0ubuntu5_i386.deb

libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dsfg-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb

libboost1.65-dev_1.65.1+dsfg-0ubuntu6_i386.deb

Is this just broken, or is something else going on?

Comment: Try to choose other mirror in ***Software & Updates*** such as *Main server*.

Comment: Both "Main Server" and "Server for United States" mirros have the same issue; however there are other mirrors that are working fine.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @BMan I have been facing the same issue. Could you please let me know which mirror works fine ?

Comment: It seems like the us mirror is working now. Run this in order to fetch pachages from the us.archive `sed -i 's|http://archive.|http://us.archive.|g' /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Not working anymore.